# Why is ⌘ displayed smaller for Chinese language code in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, unicode

On both Firefox and Chrome (but not in Safari) the following HTML displays the same symbol in very different font sizes.

```html
<div lang="en">⌘</div>
<div lang="zh">⌘</div>
```

1. Why?
2. What can I do against it? My current workaround is to do `<span lang="en">⌘</span>` on Chinese pages. But that doesn’t feel right.
3. I observed this on OS X (El Capitan) 10.11.6. How does it look on Windows?

Note:

- You might not be able to see the symbol at all on your operating system (e.g. on Android). So what I mean is the command key (unicode) symbol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_key
- Looks fine on iOS (both Safari and Chrome according to Andrew).

Comment: No repro on Chrome, Mobile

Comment: If I recall correctly, the command symbol doesn’t display at all on Android.

Comment: On iOS, seems to be fine on Chrome/Safari

Comment: Indeed, looks fine on iOS. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: They look the same on Safari 10.0, macOS Sierra. Possibly fixed?

Comment: No repro on Firefox 51, Windows 10.

Comment: @Luke: Safari was no problem in the first place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on OS X, it is a font problem.

The symbol "⌘" is only provided by a few fonts. Some of which are: **Lucida Grande**, the system font and **Heiti SC**, a Simplified-Chinese font. Since they are different fonts, we cannot expect the rendering of ⌘ is the same.

If the font you have chosen (say, Arial) does not contain the symbol "⌘", the rendering engine will try to find an alternative font that has it.

It seems Firefox and Chrome take the `lang` into account. So the **Lucida Grande** glyph is chosen for the English ⌘, and **Heiti SC** is chosen for the Chinese ⌘.

This could be fixed by adding the desired font in the font-family list:

```html
<p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif"> 
<span lang=en>english ⌘</span><span lang=zh>⌘ 中文</span> 
</p>
<p style="font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif"> 
<span lang=en>english ⌘</span><span lang=zh>⌘ 中文</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Wonderful! One last question: I did not specify any font families on my website before. Do you think it’s ok to specifiy exactly `span.command::first-line
 {font-family: 'Lucida Grande'; font-size: 15px;}` for `<span class="command key">⌘<br>command</span>`?

Comment: @mbee Should be fine, but note that outside of OS X there is usually no Lucida Grande. If you want absolute control on how it looks, use a web font (`@font-face`).